# Whether using HTML codes in the Java will only work on internet system ?

Tags: java, html, desktop

I am developing desktop application. In that I use some `HTML code` for line break (wrapping text) and change tab size in `JTabbedPane`.

If I use the application in a system without internet, will the `HTML code` will work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HTML tags in your application doesn't make it dependent on a working Internet connection. However make sure your application is not using some HTML DTD or schema spec for strict HTML validation.

I guess you could have found it yourself by trying.